# How can I print a random element from a list of strings in Racket?

Tags: list, random, racket

I have a list of words
`(define list-of-elements'(apple, carrot, tomato, cucumber))`
I have tried using `(random)` in order to print a random element from the list, but from what I have seen in the errors `(random)` is used for integers.
How could I print a random element from the list?

Comment: Or, you can `shuffle` the list and take as many elements as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [random](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=random#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._random%29%29) with [length](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=random#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._length%29%29) to get random index and then return element from list on that index.

```
(define (nth lst i)
  (if (= i 0) (car lst)
      (nth (cdr lst) (sub1 i))))

(define (random-element lst)
  (nth lst (random (length lst))))

(random-element '(apple carrot tomato cucumber))
```